# At what point GetEnumerator method executes?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, enumerator

I am confused about GetEnumerator method execution. I want to know at what point GetEnumberator method executes. I have a class A and it has 2 or 3 properties and and one of these properties is being used in GetENumerator method. If I assign a new value to that property of an object of class A and then assign same object to some veritable. Then I can see the change ResultView values. It means that when I assign that object then GetEnumerator method executes in back end. Please clarify me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetEnumerator` is called when the instance is being enumerated. Usually, this is at the start of a `foreach` clause, and very often in LINQ.

In the debugger, this is also called when you expand the results view on the instance, as you've just found out. It even warns you it will do this. So no, it doesn't get called when you change the property - it only gets called when you start reading the enumerable again - which you're doing in the debugger itself.

Comment: I did some testing and noticed that if I change a property and I am using same property in GetEnumerator method definition then GenEnumertaor method executes. I wrote an example program and if you want I can share with you.

Comment: @User1551892 Put the sample code in your question - whittle it down to the minimal code required to exhibit the behaviour.